# SQL insert into table with values selected from other tables where an external value matches

Tags: sql, select, insert

I have the following tables:

**Table1**:

| id | rarity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Common |
| 2 | Uncommon |
| 3 | Rare |

**Table2**:

| id | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Air |
| 2 | Earth |
| 3 | Fire |
| 4 | Water |

The output table already exists and the schema is the following:

| rarityID | weakness_typeID | resistance_typeID |
| --- | --- | --- |

and I should fill it with rows according to the Table2 and Table1.

For example if I'm given:

- `type` is 'Water' and 'Air'
- `rarity` is 'Common'

I'd like to add the IDs contained in `Table1` and `Table2` to this table to get the following updated output table:

| rarityID | weakness_typeID | resistance_typeID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |

I've written the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (rarityID, weakness_typeID, resistance_typeID)
    SELECT rar.id, weak.id, res.id
    FROM table1 rar, table2 weak, table2 res
    WHERE rar.rarity = `Common`
      AND weak.type = `Water`
      AND res.type = `Air`;
```

But it doesn't work, can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you please provide sample data for all 3 tables and the expected outcome after your insert?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @JonasMetzler Thanks for pointing out my question wasnt clear enough. However i've added it and provided it with some more details

Comment: @marc_s yes I understand that. But that is why i want table 3 to hold the id values from the other tables so ill be able to use a join later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your problem is that you're trying to get ids for each of your information.

If this is correct, in order to do this you need to select their ids in three separate queries like it is done in the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (rarityID, weakness_typeID, resistance_typeID)
SELECT (SELECT rar.id
        FROM   table1 rar
        WHERE  rar.rarity = 'Common') AS rarityID,
       (SELECT weak.id
        FROM   table2 weak
        WHERE  weak.type = 'Water') AS weakness_typeID,
       (SELECT weak.id
        FROM   table2 weak
        WHERE  weak.type = 'Air') AS resistance_typeID;
```

If you want to play with this code, check this [SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xquZFzSst2ra1VU6UQTLQC/0).

Comment: This looks exactly like something im trying to pull off. I'll try it out and leave a comment. The syntax make sense!

Comment: Works! Thank you a thousand sir! working both with an without 'AS' not sure if it do any different except making it more clear what you try to do.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, it's just aliasing, when you want to rename a column, just for clarity purposes.